# Opencart & vqmod - Search multiple lines - doesn't seem to find what I am looking for, is it due to tabs/whitespace?

Tags: php, xml, opencart

I am trying to use vqmod to implement a new custom field called 'Additional Description' to opencart.

In my vqmod xml file, I am trying to add an extra row to

> admin/view/template/catalog/product_form.tpl

I would like this field to appear below the existing 'Description' field, so I am using the following code:

```
    <file name="admin/view/template/catalog/product_form.tpl">
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="after"><![CDATA[
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $entry_description; ?></td>
                <td><textarea name="product_description[<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>][description]" id="description<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>"><?php echo isset($product_description[$language['language_id']]) ? $product_description[$language['language_id']]['description'] : ''; ?></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $entry_description_additional; ?></td>
                <td><textarea name="product_description_additional[<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>][description_additional]" id="description_additional<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>"><?php echo isset($product_description_additional[$language['language_id']]) ? $product_description_additional[$language['language_id']]['description_additional'] : ''; ?></textarea></td>
              </tr>
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
```

However, it doesn't seem to find the position to insert the new code. When I put in a single line of code, it finds and inserts it correctly, but not when searching for the block. Is it an issue with whitespace/tabs etc? I am pasting the code directly from the product_form.tpl so I'm not sure what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vqmod will not be able to match Ll of that. It is restricted to single lines only

Try using this instead to match it

```
<search position="after" offset="2"><![CDATA[echo $entry_description;]]></search>
```

Comment: Ah - Ok, thank you. However, do you have any idea how I can match this then, or what expression I should use to insert this new row after the description row?

Comment: Perfect, thank you. **offset** is definitely an important thing to know! The power of vqmod is indeed very impressive once you see how it works.